# Odoo 8 - How change content in div class="page"

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, invoice

i have Odoo 8 and i trying to edit content of template of invoice/order and more. I managed for now to change the header and footer entering in external_layout and external_layout_header/footer (From backend of Odoo). But i don't know how change content of div class="page".

Which files should i change?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What exactly do you want to change? The `class="page"` refers to the css class of the div element

Comment: Hi. I would change the position of the elements that are contained within. I would like to put the title of the document, for example "invoice", in the header at the top and not keep it inside the div class="page" of the document and more. In practice, i would create a custom graphics for all types of sales documents (invoice, order, delivery notes etc ...) Where do I go to change this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are hoping to do is inherit from a particular report. Once you have inherited from the report you can use xpath to select the node in that report template.

```
<template id="template_name" inherit_id="other_addon.template_name">
    <xpath expr="//div[@class='page']" position="replace">
        <!-- YOUR CONTENT HERE -->
    </xpath>
</template>
```